# Resetting Interval on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a simple image slider that I got off of the internet.  I don't know much JQuery at all, just what I understand from reading the code I have.  The code has an image slider that advances every 8 seconds, and has two buttons that will advance the images on click, either forwards or backwards.  My problem is that when I click on the button to advance, the 8 second timer does not reset such that if I click 6 seconds into the interval, the image goes to the third image 2 seconds later.  Attached is my `JQuery` code.  I tried adding `setInterval` to the `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()` functions but it did not work correctly.  I'm sorry for my lack of `JQuery` knowledge, I learned basic `JavaScript` in school and haven't used it much if at all since. Attached is the code I currently have.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 8000);

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();

        setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 8000);

    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();

        setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 8000);

    });
});
```

Comment: you're going to need to clear and reset the interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this problem because whenever you create a new Interval for moving right, your previous intervals *still exist*. I recommend you ensure that you have only one Interval by having a dedicated function to cancel and reinitialize:

```
var slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
  moveRight();
}, 8000);

function resetInterval() {
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
  slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
    moveRight();
  }, 8000);
}
```

Then, simply call this function on click:

```
$('a.control_prev').click(function() {
  moveLeft();
  resetInterval();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function() {
  moveRight();
  resetInterval();
});
```